# Search through page titles?

Tags: 7, search

Is the Search module supposed to search through the node/page titles, or just the node content?

Because, for me it is only searching through the content, and not the page titles.

Note: I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Excerpt from this [api site](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/group/search/7) "However, note that the search system already indexes all visible output of a node; i.e., everything displayed normally by hook_view() and hook_node_view().". So yes titles should be indexed also and searchable. Are you using some kind of title generation tool ? Is your index up to date ?

Comment: Thank you @drcelus

I am not using any title generation tools that I am aware of. I have over 180K nodes and am having indexing issues, so that may as well be the reason. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt say what version of Drupal your using, but if you are using D6
check this out [Views Search](http://drupal.org/project/views_search)

If not then check out [Views](http://drupal.org/project/Views)

Then I guess you just have to get the node titles and make them as a exposed filter.  So you will need to expose 1 Filter, one for the node title and then also check out [Autocomplete Filter](http://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters)

This link can also help you [Views Exposed Filter Search](http://planetghost.com/views_search_drupal)

Update :

You might also wanna take a look on this, if your not to happy about using Views
, Its more integrated to the Search API
 [Custom Search Module](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search)

Comment: Thank you @Vic

I am using drupal 7.

Does that mean I have to rewrite the search?

Comment: No I dont think so, Its all in the View your creating

Comment: Thank you @Vic

So, I would no longer be using the built-in site search but instead a search block created using the views module. Is that right?

Comment: No you are using Views, same same but different

Answer (score 0):

Try [Search configuration](http://drupal.org/project/search_config)

This module has five main functions.

1. Alter the appearance of the core node search form
2. Group content types for more meaningful searching
3. Restrict search results by the content type.
   This is a role based restriction.
4. Restrict search results from showing individual items.
   Use search_config 7.x-1.1-beta2 or above.
5. Alter the pager limit (aka number search item results per page).
   Usesearch_config 7.x-1.1-beta1 or above.